# Professional Python Frameworks for Google App Engine, in 2012?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am a C# (windows apps) developer,  so getting started with Python on GAE, I am at a bit of a loss as to what frameworks (or API's, etc) to use for "professional site development"

For example I see: Backbone, web2py, django, Enyo, Kendo, Meteor, Node.js  etc etc.

Some of these seem to be full web app frameworks, some javascript frameworks, some javascript UI frameworks...      some (like Node.js) from my research do not seem to work on GAE.

so my question: **Could a professional Python dev please give me a suggestion for framework(s) a small (5 person) dev team could pursue for rich "web 2.0" GAE/Python site development?**

Thank you so much, and sorry for being unspecific, just without industry experience, it is very difficult to objectively evaluate the best choice.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question isn't a good fit for the Q&A format, as it's open-ended.

Comment: not really programming question, very subjective responses.  But any way have a look at pyramid.  If I where building a large application which doesn't have the impedence mis-match (its not opinionated re: backend) I would use it.

Comment: Sorry for closing the question. Maybe reading a book or two about web development will help you to become familiar with web applications so you can know more what to look for and how to identify your needs and use the right set of technologies/frameworks for them. Good luck.

Comment: well asside from saying "spend N years learning python ecosystems" can anyone here actually give a "subjective" answer or at least point me to where I may find one?       

or perhaps point me to somewhere I may ask this question and get a benificial response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In web development, client-side (javascript) frameworks are mostly separate from server-side (python) frameworks, so "a Python framework ... for rich "web 2.0" development" does not make much sense - any of [Python web frameworks](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks/) can serve as a backend for your "web 2.0" application.

So, basically, you find a Python framework which suits your needs and works with GAE, then you find a JS framework which suits your needs and possibly has an integration layer with your Python framework, although the latter is not really important.

Comment: Since there are many, many ways of putting together a python GAE app, any suggestions?   I am personally looking into backbone with a ui like Kendo,  but as I have not done this before, any "gotchas" that you may think of?

Comment: Pyramid or Django are two obvious choices: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/tutorials/gae/index.html; https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django  I personally would use Pyramid since it is storage-agnostic. Both of them can be used with Backbone and Kendo. Just start building a "hello world" app to get a feeling...

Comment: I have been developing on appengine since 2008 (paid to do it ;-) using python and can't say I have ever heard of backbone or kendo ui used with python projects.  Doesn't mean they aren't used but they are certainly not particularly visible in appengine/python circles.

Comment: Backbone and Kendo are both client-side JavaScript libraries - there's nothing that can prevent them being used with GAE. My point is that choice of the backend language/framework has almost nothing to do with the choice of client-side JS framework. There are some exceptions, of course, such as GWT and Pyjamas.

Comment: right, thank you so much for your time Sergey, I much appreciate your taking the time to answer me.

Comment: and, thank you for mentioning Pyramid, i'll give that a look